# While creating a react app, I am getting the error, "npm ERR! enoent – This is related to npm not being able to find a file"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, terminal

I am trying to convert my basic HTML into a react app, but when I tried to create a react app with the command,

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

the command returns me, "npm ERR! enoent – This is related to npm not being able to find a file". Is there anything I am overlooking here?

I have searched the internet for the correct command, and I didn't sway from the instructions. I have also searched for this error on YouTube, but it only shows solutions about not being able to `npm start`.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem but if you're starting with a new project you may want to use vite instead. https://vitejs.dev/guide/ CRA is dead. https://dev.to/ag2byte/create-react-app-is-officially-dead-h7o

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the **Node version** is working for me. My node version is 16.16.0 and npm version is 8.11.0